# Troubleshooting ggplot()/maps() Runtime Issue

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, runtime-error

Alright, so I'm struggling a bit in creating this map. The following code gives me [this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKMe1.png), which is the map that I really want to use.

```
map(database= "world", ylim=c(15,90), xlim=c(-180,-24), fill = TRUE, projection = 'gilbert')
```

This is the code I used to save the map information.

```
map.dat <- map_data(map(database= "world", ylim=c(15,90), xlim=c(-180,-24), fill = TRUE, projection = 'gilbert'))
```

Now, when I run the following code, it gives me the error 'Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'group' not found'. I'm not sure what that means.

```
ggplot(map.dat, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=region)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  geom_point(data = basindf, aes(x = basindf$latitude, y = basindf$longitude)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I had set 'group = NULL' and 'fill = NULL' and that seems to allow me to plot, but it only displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMfW5.png), which is not what I want. The map is gone!

What can I do to fix this? Also, I want to move away from the points and create lines. How would I be able to make lines based on a certain id?

EDIT: Seems that some of you needed basindf to troubleshoot. I've added the first 20 lines below.

```
"","id","year","month","date","basin","latitude","longitude","wind speed"
"1","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-03,"EP",-93.8,14,30
"2","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-03,"EP",-94,14.5,30
"3","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-03,"EP",-94.2,15,30
"4","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-03,"EP",-94.3,15.5,30
"5","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-04,"EP",-94.4,16,30
"6","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-04,"EP",-94.5,16.5,30
"7","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-04,"EP",-94.6,17,30
"8","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-04,"EP",-94.7,17.5,30
"9","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-05,"EP",-94.8,18,30
"10","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-05,"EP",-94.9,18.5,30
"11","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-05,"NA",-94.9,18.7,35
"12","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-05,"NA",-94.7,18.8,45
"13","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-06,"NA",-94.4,18.9,55
"14","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-06,"NA",-94,19.1,60
"15","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-06,"NA",-93.7,19.3,65
"16","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-06,"NA",-93.3,19.5,75
"17","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-07,"NA",-92.9,19.7,85
"18","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-07,"NA",-92.5,20,90
"19","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-07,"NA",-92,20.3,90
"20","1902276N14266",1902,"October",1902-10-07,"NA",-91.5,20.7,90
```

Comment: I have the same error of @MrFlick, ggplot2 1.0.1, maps 2.3.10.

Comment: I've added the first 20 lines of basindf. This should help, as I still get the error when I turn basindf into the first 20 lines.

Answer (score 1):

You have two main problems.

First, the error you are getting is because you are sepecufying `aes()` in the `ggplot()` call which means that those values inherit to all layers. That means it's trying to set a `group=` in the `geom_point` layer as well but you do not have groups for that layer. You can disable the inherited aesthetics with

```
ggplot(map.dat, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=region)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  geom_point(data = basindf, aes(x = basindf$latitude, y = basindf$longitude), inherit.aes=FALSE) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

or you can sepecy the aes per layer

```
ggplot(map.dat) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=region)) +
  geom_point(data = basindf, aes(x = basindf$latitude, y = basindf$longitude)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Your other problem is that you transformed your map data with a projection but not your point data. 
[image]

You can transform your data with `mapproj` so they are both on the same scale

```
ggplot(map.dat) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=region)) +
  geom_point(data = data.frame(mapproject(basindf$latitude, basindf$longitude, "gilbert")), aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")
```

This gives

[image]

Comment: Ahh, that helps a lot. The points are still in the wrong place, though?The code: "map(); points(basindf$latitude, basindf$longitude, pch = 20, col = '#C0000020', lwd = .5)" has the points hugging North America.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it was not working was because you set global `aes` parameters in the first call to `aes`, and ggplot2 was looking for group and region in the `geom_points` call to group and fill the points.

This technically works:

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
        geom_polygon(data = map.dat, aes(x =long, y = lat, group = group, fill = region)) +
        geom_point(data = basindf, aes(x = latitude, y = longitude)) +
        theme(legend.position = "none")
```

You can see your map in the bottom right, very tiny. You want to rescale your map to lat/long, or your data to whatever you have in your map.

EDIT see the answer from @MrFlick for plot rescaling.

Comment: But the position is wrong, no?

When I do: "map(); points(basindf$latitude, basindf$longitude, pch = 20, col = '#C0000020', lwd = .5)"...it seems to hug the map?

Comment: I'm not sure where your points are supposed to be - where do you expect them?

Comment: Okay, this is really weird. So I've been subsetting the data values. When I select the first 1100 rows, the points are where they should be. But when I select the first 1200 or higher, the points don't show up on the map in their proper locations. I don't know how to send you the csv. :(

Comment: You should ask another question if its not directly related to the ggplot trouble. Try and find a minimal reproducible example, and then depending on the size of the csv, try pastebin, dropbox or just pasting a dput() of you data in the new question.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was a problem with the projection. So I just removed that.